# Timeout jQuery effects

Tags: jquery, timeout

I am trying to have an element fade in, then in 5000 ms fade back out again. I know I can do something like:

```
setTimeout(function () { $(".notice").fadeOut(); }, 5000);
```

But that will only control the fade out, would I add the above on the callback?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

**Update:** As of jQuery 1.4 you can use the `.delay( n )` method. http://api.jquery.com/delay/

```
$('.notice').fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
```

**Note**: `$.show()` and `$.hide()` by default are not queued, so if you want to use `$.delay()` with them, you need to configure them that way:

```
$('.notice')
    .show({duration: 0, queue: true})
    .delay(2000)
    .hide({duration: 0, queue: true});
```

---

You could possibly use the Queue syntax, this might work:

```
jQuery(function($){ 

var e = $('.notice'); 
e.fadeIn(); 
e.queue(function(){ 
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    e.dequeue(); 
  }, 2000 ); 
}); 
e.fadeOut('fast'); 

});
```

or you could be really ingenious and make a jQuery function to do it.

```
(function($){ 

  jQuery.fn.idle = function(time)
  { 
      var o = $(this); 
      o.queue(function()
      { 
         setTimeout(function()
         { 
            o.dequeue(); 
         }, time);
      });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

which would ( in theory , working on memory here ) permit you do to this:

```
$('.notice').fadeIn().idle(2000).fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: I am wondering why you are using the queue when a simple usage of setTimeout will work as well.

Comment: because if you use the queue, its easy to add new events to and reuse the code, and code reuse is a GoodThing™

Comment: Note that, as also stated in the jQuery API documentation, delay() should really only be used for things related to the effects queue. If you need a timeout for something else, setTimeout() is still the way to go.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the link @bottlenecked , I guess the reason that my example is so similar to the new feature added to jQuery is that there's a notable chain of influence from this answer to http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4102  =P

Answer (score 23):

I just figured it out below:

```
$(".notice")
   .fadeIn( function() 
   {
      setTimeout( function()
      {
         $(".notice").fadeOut("fast");
      }, 2000);
   });
```

I will keep the post for other users!

Answer (score 14):

Great hack by @strager. Implement it into jQuery like this:

```
jQuery.fn.wait = function (MiliSeconds) {
    $(this).animate({ opacity: '+=0' }, MiliSeconds);
    return this;
}
```

And then use it as:

```
$('.notice').fadeIn().wait(2000).fadeOut('slow');
```

Answer (score 11):

You can do something like this:

```
$('.notice')
    .fadeIn()
    .animate({opacity: '+=0'}, 2000)   // Does nothing for 2000ms
    .fadeOut('fast');
```

Sadly, you can't just do .animate({}, 2000) -- I think this is a bug, and will report it.

Answer (score 7):

Ben Alman wrote a sweet plugin for jQuery called doTimeout. It has a lot of nice features!

Check it out here: *[jQuery doTimeout: Like setTimeout, but better](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/)*.

Answer (score 5):

To be able to use it like that, you need to return `this`. Without the return, fadeOut('slow'), will not get an object to perform that operation on.

I.e.:

```
  $.fn.idle = function(time)
  {
      var o = $(this);
      o.queue(function()
      {
         setTimeout(function()
         {
            o.dequeue();
         }, time);
      });
      return this;              //****
  }
```

Then do this:

```
$('.notice').fadeIn().idle(2000).fadeOut('slow');
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with only a few lines of jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    // make sure img is hidden - fade in
    $('img').hide().fadeIn(2000);

    // after 5 second timeout - fade out
    setTimeout(function(){$('img').fadeOut(2000);}, 5000);
});​
```

---

see the fiddle below for a working example...

### http://jsfiddle.net/eNxuJ/78/