# How to create an "endless" scrolling slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I know a good bit of JS and I'm familiar with jQuery, and I'm trying to create an "endless" slideshow (like the one on http://thisismedium.com/), where the images scroll -- one right behind the other -- and when it reaches the end it loops.

I don't really know how to start, so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I created a slideshow before that automatically switched images and let you click Next and Previous, but I'm stuck here. =/.

Comment: Possible duplicate, might want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001770/jquery-slideshow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at the jQuery Cycle module.

They have a good beginner introduction here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/begin.html

I've used this for a couple of projects, and it's pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

[Try this](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) and use the scrollLeft effect.

If you need assistance implementing it, just ask.