# Newbie jQuery question: Need slideshow to rotate automatically, not just when clicking navigation

Tags: jquery

This is my first post, so please forgive me if this question has been asked a million times. I'm a self professed jQuery hack and I need a little guidance on taking this script I found and adapting it to my needs.

Anyway, what I'm making is an image slide show with navigation. The script I found does this, but does not automatically cycle through the images. I'm using jQuery 1.3.2 and would rather stick with that than using the newer library. I would also prefer to edit what is already here rather than start from scratch.

Anywho, here's the html:

```
 <div id="slideshow-container"> 
        <div id="myslide">
            <div class="cover">
                <div class="mystuff">
                    <img alt="&nbsp;" src="image1.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="mystuff">
                    <img alt="&nbsp;" src="image2.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="mystuff">
                    <img alt="&nbsp;" src="image3.jpg" />           
                </div>
                <div class="mystuff">
                    <img alt="&nbsp;" src="image4.jpg" />           
                </div>

            </div> <!-- end of div cover -->
        </div>  <!-- end of div myslide -->
    <div id="button">
        <a class="button1 active" rel="1" href="#">1</a>
        <a class="button2" rel="2" href="#">2</a>
        <a class="button3" rel="3" href="#">3</a>
        <a class="button4" rel="4" href="#">4</a>
    </div> <!-- end of div button--> 
</div><!-- end of slideshow-container -->
```

And here's the jQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#button a').click(function(){
            var integer = $(this).attr('rel');
            $('#myslide .cover').css({left:-820*(parseInt(integer)-1)}).hide().fadeIn(); /*----- Width of div #mystuff (here 820) ------ */
            $('#button a').each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
                if($(this).hasClass('button'+integer)){
                    $(this).addClass('active')}
            });
        }); 
    });
    </script>
```

Here's where I got the script: [http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/04/07/create-lightweight-jquery-fade-manual-slideshow/](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/04/07/create-lightweight-jquery-fade-manual-slideshow)

Again, if this question is too basic for this site please let me know and possibly provide a reference link or two. Thanks a ton!

**Edit:** 
I actually tried Matt's suggestion earlier but was unclear on the syntax of using setInterval with what I was working with. Here is the code that I was working with earlier, that isolates the image change. When this is loaded, the initial image loads with a fade animation but nothing else happens.

```
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var integer = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('#myslide .cover').css({left:-820*(parseInt(integer)-1)}).hide().fadeIn(); /*----- Width of div #mystuff (here 820) ------ */
    });
    </script>
```

Obviously this doesn't include setInterval() but that's because, frankly, I'm clueless about the syntax and application of setInterval().

**Solution provided by nate and adapted slightly:**

```
   <script>
    // Consider calculating these values instead of hard-coding them.
    // The "currrentFrame" is the id with the "active" class,
    // and the totalFrames could be counted with jQuery.   
    var currentFrame = 1; 
    var totalFrames = 4;
    var timeoutId;

    $(document).ready(function (){
        // Handle the numbered button clicks
        $('#button a').click(function(){showFrame($(this).attr('rel'));
        });
        //automatically handle slide rotation
        $('document').ready(function(){getNextFrame($(this).attr('rel'));
        setInterval("getNextFrame()",3000); // time in milliseconds
        });
    });

    // I put the contents of the original click handler here
    // so that it could be called by both the button and the timer.
    function showFrame(integer){           
        $('#myslide .cover').css({left:-820*(parseInt(integer)-1)}).hide().fadeIn(); 
        $('#button a').each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            if($(this).hasClass('button'+integer)){
                $(this).addClass('active')}
        });
    // storing the current frame globally
    currentFrame = integer;
    }; 

    // determine the next frame using the 
    // currentFrame global. Again, a better way
    // to do this could be to calculate the current
    // frame with jquery...
    function getNextFrame() {
        currentFrame = parseInt(currentFrame);
        currentFrame++;
        if(currentFrame > totalFrames)
            currentFrame = 1;
        showFrame(currentFrame);


    }
    </script>
```

Comment: So, you want it to cycle the images automatically. Do you want to hide the buttons as well?

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the reply.

No, I'd like to keep the navigation functional as well as have the slides cycle automatically. Otherwise I'd scrap it all and just use the Cycle plugin. In my mind, it seems like I have enough here to add an extra function or two to get the thing to cycle automatically, but we all know that just because we think it'll be easy doesn't mean it will be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two problems to solve here:

1. Create a function that can determine the next frame.
2. Call that function on a given interval.

Split out the code that displayes the current frame as its own function, as in `showFrame()`.

Then make a function that determines which frame to call next, as in `getNextFrame()`.

Finally, add buttons that call `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` as needed, as in `toggleSlideShow()`.

But once you get this working, make another attempt at Cycle or another such plugin.

```
    <script>
    // Consider calculating these values instead of hard-coding them.
    // The "currrentFrame" is the id with the "active" class,
    // and the totalFrames could be counted with jQuery.   
    var currentFrame = 1; 
    var totalFrames = 4;
    var timeoutId;

    $(document).ready(function (){
        // Handle the numbered button clicks
        $('#button a').click(function(){showFrame($(this).attr('rel'));
        });
        //handle the start/stop clicks
        $('#controlButton a').click(function(){toggleSlideShow($(this).attr('rel'));
        });
    });

    // I put the contents of the original click handler here
    // so that it could be called by both the button and the timer.
    function showFrame(integer){           
        $('#myslide .cover').css({left:-820*(parseInt(integer)-1)}).hide().fadeIn(); 
        $('#button a').each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            if($(this).hasClass('button'+integer)){
                $(this).addClass('active')}
        });
        // storing the current frame globally
        currentFrame = integer;
        }; 

    // determine the next frame using the 
    // currentFrame global. Again, a better way
    // to do this could be to calculate the current
    // frame with jquery...
    function getNextFrame() {
        currentFrame = parseInt(currentFrame);
        currentFrame++;
        if(currentFrame > totalFrames)
            currentFrame = 1;
        showFrame(currentFrame);
    }

    // Start and stop the slide show.
    // The important part here are the setInterval and
    // clearInterval functions.
    function toggleSlideShow(state){
        // using the same technique for the start
        // and stop buttons
        $('#controlButton a').each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            if($(this).hasClass('button'+state)){
                $(this).addClass('active')}
                });
            if(state == "Start") {
                //Store the timeoutId for later...
                timeoutId = setInterval("getNextFrame()",1000); // time in milliseconds
                }
            else {
                //...so it can be used to stop the show.
                clearInterval(timeoutId);
            }
     }
    </script>
```

Here is the source for the start/stop buttons I added. You can put this where you like--I inserted it after the `button` div.

```
    <div id="controlButton">
        <a class="buttonStart" rel="Start" href="#">Start</a>
        <a class="buttonStop" rel="Stop" href="#">Stop</a>
    </div>
```

I also defined `.buttonStart,.buttonStop` in the CSS file.

Comment: Nate you're a gentleman and a scholar. The code you provided worked splendidly even after I got my plebeian hands on it and set it so the cycling is automatic without the aid of a start / stop button. Thanks a ton! And you're right, a plugin would have been a much more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Justin, check out the section on `setInterval()` on [this page](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/).

Basically, if you can isolate your code to cycle the pictures into a simple function call, you would just do:

`setInterval("myFunction()", 500)`

which would call your function every 500ms (.5 seconds). 
Now, things get a little trickier if you want to be able to stop the interval running. In that case, you need to get the "hInterval" (the interval handle) which is returned from `setInterval`. Then you can use that in a call to `clearInterval()`

So that would be done like this:

```
// set your interval and capture the handle
var hInt = setInterval("myFunction()", 500);

< blah blah blah > 

// clear the interval so it doesn't fire again
clearInterval(hInt);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solution, but if you really want to just add-on to the existing function, you'll most likely use setInterval or [setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316278/timeout-jquery-effects) to call a modified version of your existing function every x seconds.

And while this is certainly possible (I'm not expert enough to write this off the top of my head), it's something that's built right in to the [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin you mentioned. Which could be quite easily implemented into your existing code (I believe).

Sorry I can't offer better advice at the moment.

Comment: Matt this is the initial road I was traveling down but ran into my own shortcoming understanding jQuery syntax. I'll append what I was originally working with to the post. If I'm barking up the wrong tree then it's probably time to find a version of Cycle that's compatible with 1.3.2