# Swap divs after a certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using Javascript or JQuery, I want to replace a div 20 seconds after the page has loaded. In short, div A gets shown first and it's replaced 20 seconds later by div B.

To be clear, this isn't meant to be a rotating animation. The swap occurs only once, in a set interval after the page has been loaded, and without any further interaction from the end user. The only way the swap would occur again is if the page were reloaded.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this.][1] Anyhow the link should show you what to do. Use a setTimeout() function.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316278/timeout-jquery-effects

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in your document ready handler:

```
$("#divA").delay(20000).fadeOut(function() {
     $("#divB").fadeIn();
     $(this).remove();
});
```

With some CSS to hide the second div initially:

```
#divB { display : none; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N3tdd/

Obviously use whatever selectors are appropriate to your markup, and if you can't or don't want to hide div B with a CSS rule you could just add `$("#divB").hide();` before the above code.