# JavaScript: get code to run every minute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to make some JS code be executed every 60 seconds? I'm thinking it might be possible with a `while` loop, but is there a neater solution? JQuery welcome, as always.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316278/timeout-jquery-effects

Comment: setInterval(expression, timeout); runs the code/function in intervals, with the length of the timeout between them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a function every 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138756/calling-a-function-every-60-seconds)

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval):

```
setInterval(function() {
    // your code goes here...
}, 60 * 1000); // 60 * 1000 milsec
```

The function returns an id you can clear your interval with [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval):

```
var timerID = setInterval(function() {
    // your code goes here...
}, 60 * 1000); 

clearInterval(timerID); // The setInterval it cleared and doesn't run anymore.
```

---

A "sister" function is [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)/[clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout) look them up.

---

If you want to run a function on page init and then 60 seconds after, 120 sec after, ...:

```
function fn60sec() {
    // runs every 60 sec and runs on init.
}
fn60sec();
setInterval(fn60sec, 60*1000);
```

Comment: +1 for `60 * 1000`, but it's also a good idea to define the function outside rather than passing an anonymous function.

Comment: Question, though: if I put that, will the code be executed on the loading of the page, or will it happen 60 seconds after the loading?

Comment: @Bluefire it runs 60 seconds after init

Answer (score 16):

You could use `setInterval` for this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction () {
    console.log('Executed!');
}

var interval = setInterval(function () { myFunction(); }, 60000);
</script>
```

Disable the timer by setting `clearInterval(interval)`.

See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p6NJt/2/

Answer (score 4):

**to call a function on exactly the start of every minute**

```js
let date = new Date();
let sec = date.getSeconds();
setTimeout(()=>{
  setInterval(()=>{
    // do something
  }, 60 * 1000);
}, (60 - sec) * 1000);
```

Comment: If it's important to continue executing at the start of every minute for any moderate length of time, it's worth noting that JS's `setInterval` is not very reliable at exact time keeping, and this will likely drift further away from the start of the minute the longer it runs.