# Repeat code every x seconds but not if [insert check here]

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304471/javascript-get-code-to-run-every-minute), where I found out how to make code be repeated every x seconds. Is it possible to make an event that can change this? I.e. I have a checkbox which is meant to control whether this is repeated or not, so I figured I'd need something like this:

```
$(checkbox).bind("change", function() {
    switch(whether if it is ticked or not) {
        case [ticked]:
            // Make the code repeat, while preserving the ability to stop it repeating
        case [unticked]:
            // Make the code stop repeating, while preserving the ability to start again
    }
});
```

I have no idea what I could put in the `case`s.

Comment: It looks like the answer to your other question already addresses this. `clearInterval` allows you to stop a setInterval call.

Comment: Does it let me start it again?

Comment: If you use the general structure above yes, it would whenever the checkbox is changed.

Comment: I added a demo to my answer, I hope it will help you get the whole picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function fooFunc() {
    $('#foo').text(+new Date());
}
var id;
var shouldBeStopped = false;
$('input').change(function() {
    if (shouldBeStopped) 
        clearInterval(id);
    else 
        id = setInterval(fooFunc, 200);

    shouldBeStopped = !shouldBeStopped;
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9f2hG/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by assigning your setInterval function to a variable.

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {  }, 1000);
```

and then you can stop setInterval by

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

p.s. 
to start your interval you need to call `var interval = setInterval(function() {  }, 1000);` again

Answer (score 2):

You can either stop and start the interval:

```
var timer;

function start() {
  timer = window.setInterval(function(){
    // do something
  }, 1000);
}

function stop() {
  window.clearInterval(timer);
}

start();

$(checkbox).bind("change", function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    start();
  } else {
    stop();
  }
});
```

Or you can have a flag causing the interval to skip the code:

```
var enabled = true;

var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
  if (!enabled) {
    // do something
  }
}, 1000);

$(checkbox).bind("change", function() {
  enabled = $(this).is(':checked');
});
```