# jQuery.load setTimeout not working

Tags: jquery, load, settimeout

I'm loading content from a PhP file into a div. It loads fine once, but I want it to reload every 5 seconds to show updates to the database. From looking on this site and others this should work fine, but it doesn't.

```
 <div id="Total">

     $(document).ready(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#Total').load('points.php');
      },5000); });


  </div>
```

Comment: `setTimeout` will only call the callback *once*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: get code to run every minute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304471/javascript-get-code-to-run-every-minute)

Comment: Place the script outside of the #Total div and put it inside <script> tags. The load will replace the html inside the div,

Comment: I had setInterval to start with it wasn't working. I moved it to outside the <div> and added the script tags and it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and put the script outside of Total

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      setInterval(function(){
        $('#Total').load('points.php');
      },5000); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setInterval()` for execution. `setTimeout()` will only execute once.
You need to also make sure your script is contained within a `<script>` block

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            $('#Total').load('points.php');
        },5000);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout only triggers once. 
You should use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) insted.