# Run a JavaScript command every X minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JavaScript function

```
/* Use this method to send a message to the active chatwindow */
function sendMessageToActiveWindow(message) {
  swfobject.getObjectById('lightIRC').sendMessageToActiveWindow(message);
}
```

I want to set up an array of messages and then every X minutes use `sendMessageToActiveWindow(message)` with a randomly selected message from the array.

Is it possible to do such a thing in JavaScript/jQuery etc. and any examples?

Comment: _"Is it possible to do such a thing in JavaScript/jQuery etc.?"_ Yup

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304471/javascript-get-code-to-run-every-minute

Answer (score 5):

Sure, how about:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var message = messages[Math.floor(Math.random()*messages.length)]
    sendMessageToActiveWindow(message)
}, 60000);
```

This will pick a random `message` from the `messages` array and fire your method, every minute.

Comment: That will delay it for 60000 ms.  `setInterval` is what you meant, probably.

Comment: @aelieo -- Yep, made the edit, thank ya!

Comment: Ah wow, and just do something like `var messages = ["Hello", "Goodbye", "Ola"];`?