# How to add 2 to the current value at every one minute?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

My HTML and CSS code is here. Every no. is in diffrent span tag.
I need like 152,242 after 1 minute, 152,244 after 2 minutes and so on. I was trying to do it with jquery but i did not get the perfect output.

```css
#hp_header .number{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
#hp_header .number .number_inner{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #282828;
    font-family: SourceSansPro-Regular !important;
    font-size: 32px;
}
#hp_header .number .count{
    font-family: SourceSansPro-Regular !important;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #f0f1b4;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: #282828;
    margin: 0px 5px;
}
#hp_header .number .members_count {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #282828;
    font-family: SourceSansPro-Regular !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="hp_header">
  <span class="number">
    <span class="number_inner">
      <span class="count">1</span>
      <span class="count">5</span>
      <span class="count">2</span>
      ,
      <span class="count">2</span>
      <span class="count">4</span>
      <span class="count">2</span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you tried and what it was that didn't work for you.

Comment: This has to be done with Javascript. HTML and CSS itself cannot help updating your values. Show us your JS.

Comment: I am try normal javascrpt, i think it is not usefull for you.

Comment: `setInterval(function() { ...your code goes here..}, 60 * 1000);` It will run every one min.

Comment: Only time is not important but i add this value in diffrent span. Here is all character in diffrent span. @ChoncholMahmud

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13304481/6619234 hope it helps you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope below code will help you. For testing i put 2 seconds interval(2000). You can make it (60000) for each minute

```js
setInterval(oneSecondFunction, 2000);
function oneSecondFunction() {
   total = document.getElementsByClassName('count').length; 
   values = document.getElementsByClassName('count');
   current_value='';
  
   for(i=0;i<total;i++)
   {
    
    current_value+=values[i].innerHTML;
    
   }
   new_value = parseInt(current_value)+2;
   
   new_value_string=new_value.toString();

   for(j=0;j<new_value_string.length;j++)
   {
    values[j].innerHTML = new_value_string[j];
   }
  
}
```

```css
#hp_header .number{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
#hp_header .number .number_inner{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #282828;
    font-family: SourceSansPro-Regular !important;
    font-size: 32px;
}
#hp_header .number .count{
    font-family: SourceSansPro-Regular !important;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #f0f1b4;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: #282828;
    margin: 0px 5px;
}
#hp_header .number .members_count {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #282828;
    font-family: SourceSansPro-Regular !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="hp_header">
  <span class="number">
    <span class="number_inner">
      <span class="count">1</span>
      <span class="count">5</span>
      <span class="count">2</span>
      ,
      <span class="count">2</span>
      <span class="count">4</span>
      <span class="count">2</span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Azeez Kallayi