# How can I automatically update stock prices every minute without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I want to update stock prices on my page every minute and display new prices without refreshing the page. Could you please help me how to do this.

```
 $(function () {
    var stocks = [];
    var symbols = ['AAPL', 'MSFT'];

    symbols.forEach(symbol => makeAjaxCall(symbol));

    function makeAjaxCall(param) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=" + param + "&interval=1min&apikey=8TKKZE0GET944FMW",
            success: function (result) {
                stocks = result;
                getPrices();
            }
        });
    }

    function getPrices() {
        var metaData = stocks["Meta Data"],
            timeSeries = stocks["Time Series (1min)"],
            symbol = metaData["2. Symbol"];
        var priceList2 = '';
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(lastDate).forEach(function (val, idx, array) {
            priceList += val + ': ' + lastDate[val] + '<br>';
        });

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += '<div class="eachStock"><a href="#" data-stock="' + symbol + '">' + symbol + '</a></div><div>' + priceList + '</div>';
    }
});
```

My html file:

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: get code to run every minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304471/javascript-get-code-to-run-every-minute)

Comment: [setInterval\(\)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First wrap all your code in a function call:

```
const loadData = () => {
    var stocks = [];
    var symbols = ['AAPL', 'MSFT'];

    symbols.forEach(symbol => makeAjaxCall(symbol));

    function makeAjaxCall(param) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=" + param + "&interval=1min&apikey=8TKKZE0GET944FMW",
            success: function (result) {
                stocks = result;
                getPrices();
            }
        });
    }

    function getPrices() {
        var metaData = stocks["Meta Data"],
            timeSeries = stocks["Time Series (1min)"],
            symbol = metaData["2. Symbol"];
        var priceList2 = '';
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(lastDate).forEach(function (val, idx, array) {
            priceList += val + ': ' + lastDate[val] + '<br>';
        });

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += '<div class="eachStock"><a href="#" data-stock="' + symbol + '">' + symbol + '</a></div><div>' + priceList + '</div>';
    }
};
```

You need to make sure it can be called many times, in which it mustn't append values, but replace (just clear the div at the begining, like `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ''`). Then, you can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to call your function every so often. Don't forget to start it only when the page is loaded (you were using jquery for that, there are other options):

```
const TIME = 2 * 1000; // time in millis for next update
$(() => {
    loadData();
    setInterval(loadData, TIME);
});
```

Note that if the request takes more time than `TIME`, you might get concurrency issues. For a better solution, take a look at [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). They'll allow for a cleaner code.

If you are using jquery just for request making and the 'has page loaded' event, you might want to learn newer alternatives (like the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and [this event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)).