# How do I send alerts every minute?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to html and javascript but I was wondering how I could go about sending alerts like this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_alert every minute or so.

Comment: the same thing.. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Please see the below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304471/javascript-get-code-to-run-every-minute

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(() => {
  // your code
}, 1000)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 0):

javascript have a method to repeat something like a task every so often, this method is the function `setInterval` this function repeat that you want.

**Javascript**:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    alert("Hello"); 
}, 3000);
```

For example this method shown every 3 seconds an alert that say "Hello", if you want repeat a task every **3** **minutures** you need change `3000` to `180000` like this:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    alert("Hello"); 
}, 180000); // repeat every 3 minutes
```

Here is the [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) of the function.

I hope it helps you, regards!