# How do I go about delaying javascript execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript code which displays a form on loading the web page. I need the code to execute 2 minutes after the visitor has been on the website. How do I go about it? Below is my code:

```
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("dialog").innerHTML="";}, 120000);

$(document).ready(function() {  

        var id = '#dialog';

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9);  

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(2000);     

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

});
```

Comment: This post may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304471/javascript-get-code-to-run-every-minute

Comment: ..and what does your code do / not do?  You're already using setTimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code must be INSIDE the `setTimeout()`, not OUTSIDE. Try it...

Answer (score 0):

Use [`window.setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout):

> The `setTimeout()` method [...] sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once the timer expires.
>
> ## Syntax
>
> ```
> var timeoutID = scope.setTimeout(function[, delay, arg1, arg2, ...]);
> var timeoutID = scope.setTimeout(function[, delay]);
> var timeoutID = scope.setTimeout(code[, delay]);
> ```

So in your case, you could do this:

```
// When the page first loads...
$(document).ready(function() {
  // ...wait for two minutes...
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    // ...and then run this code.
  }, 120000)
})
```

More details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout